# Hook to create/add a database dump file to repository on git pull

Tags: database, git, hook

My aim is to minimize the steps needed to locally clone my website + database.

I have a central git **repository on a webserver** and a **local clone**. When I pull updates on my local machine, not only should I get the latest file versions from the remote repository but also should a script run on this webserver to dump the live database and additionally add it to the repository prior to delivering the pull.

My guess is that I need the following actions to happen on the remote machine when I fire git pull on the local machine prior to delivering the repository:

- Create database dump file, e.g. dump.sql (by exectuting mysqldump)
- Add dump.sql to repository
- Commit dump.sql to repository

… and only then deliver the pull to the local machine.

What kind of git hook should I use for this? 
I'd also appreciate any additional experience with such a scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git help hooks` lists the types of hooks and how they work, but there isn't a hook that you can use to do what you want (you'd need something like `pre-upload` that would be executed by `git-upload-pack`).

However, you could create a wrapper script around `git-upload-pack` on the server that performs the necessary actions and then executes the real `git-upload-pack` command:

1. find the `git-upload-pack` executable
2. rename it to `git-upload-pack.real`
3. create a new script called `git-upload-pack` somewhere in `PATH` that does the following:

   1. use the arguments to find the Git repository
   2. `cd` into the Git repository
   3. if `hooks/pre-upload` exists and is an executable file:

      1. run it
      2. if the hook exited with a non-zero status:

         1. print an error message to standard error
         2. exit with a non-zero return value
   4. run `git-upload-pack.real` with the original command-line arguments
4. create a `hooks/pre-upload` script in your Git repository that does whatever you want

Comment: I'm very intrigued by this idea; can you offer any suggestions on how to write wrappers around `git-upload-pack`? I searched around Google and answers are sparse to non-existent. Do you point to your wrapper from the `.gitconfig` file, or do you just make sure your wrapper is in a higher-priority place in your environment's execution path?

Comment: Thanks, I had a suspicion it was something bare-metal like that :-) Now to try to figure out how to isolate that to specific repos only...